# Can I increase download timeout in Artifactory?

Tags: artifactory

I'm getting error like this:

`2018-01-16 09:56:17,354 [http-nio-8081-exec-8] [ERROR] (o.a.r.RemoteRepoBase:772) - IO error while trying to download resource 'pp-libs:ru/programpark/vector/10/vector-10.zip': org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to 192.168.3.20:8111 [/192.168.3.20] failed: connect timed out`

in Artifactory log.

The file is half-gigabyte long and the channel to remote repo is not very wide.
Remote repo is an artifactory itself.
I'm not sure who closes the connection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to increase the `Socket Timeout` in the `Network Settings`. See https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Advanced+Settings

Comment: I noticed that there are `read timeouts` also. `IO error while trying to download resource 'pp-libs:ru/programpark/vector/11/vector-11.zip': org.jfrog.storage.binstore.ifc.ClientInputStreamException: Failed to read stream: Read timed out`. Will increasing the `socket timeout` help here too?

Comment: I think so. Give it a try

Comment: Socket timeout should be resolved by this param. 
If you increase it and still see that you are having connection drop, check if you have any proxy that can close the connection.

Comment: This setting is only available for Remote type repositories in case of Pull replication.